# Foreign key referencing identityuser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I want to know if this is a good practice.

I am building an application with more than one model entities; `profile.cs`, `social.cs`, `skill.cs` etc and I want each user to have a profile, have a social link, have a special skill and so on.

I want to know if it is a good practice to reference all this entities in `identityuser.cs` and if yes, are you saying that identityuser can have more than one foreign key?

```
Public class profile{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string name{get;set}
    public string phone{get;set}
}

//other properties and entities
```

Comment: I don't see any problem in do these references, also, I can't see problem into have multiples foreign keys too. The only thing that I always try to avoid, is to use composed PK.

Comment: Sorry i dnt get you. Can you elaborate further?

Comment: What exactly didn't you understand?